# Can I make a car battery charger using an ordinary transformer or does the secondary winding have to have a center tap

Tags: battery-charging, automotive

I am a mechanical engineer with some electrical experience. I have a battery charger which has a center tap on the secondary winding and uses two diodes for rectification. When set on low it charges at about 2 A DC. I am trying to make one similar to that but I had no idea about the number of turns of the center tap secondary. So I decide to design my own non center tap transformer using some transformer design apps. I have done all the work making the non center tap transformer and am using a full bridge rectifier for rectification. but when on low setting, instead of charging at 2 A it's charging at 10 A. The DC voltage on both machines is very nearly the same at about 15 V. I am puzzled why the charging currents are so different. Can any one help?

Comment: Show us the circuit. Also do a web search for "car battery charger circuit" and you will see plenty of circuits which can be used. In commercial chargers, they use the center tap so that only **two** diodes are needed instead of four like in a bridge rectifier. So it is just a cost saving. There is no need for a center tap if you use a bridge rectifier.

Comment: *The DC voltage on both machines is very nearly the same at about 15 volts* Measured how? Is there a smoothing capacitor? If it is a non-smoothed voltage then that 15 V is not accurate. I prefer a smoothed voltage of ~17 V and then use an LM317 to make an accurate 13.8 V for the battery. The LM317 will limit the current to 1.5 A and not charge above 13.8 V which is the highest voltage to which you should charge a car battery

Comment: The battery is like a huge supercap

Answer (score 2):

> Can I make a car battery charger using an ordinary transformer or does
> the secondary winding have to have a center tap

The transformer may or may not have the centre tap.

**Transformer with centre tap**

[image]

The transformer with centre tap is to be wound for double the required secondary voltage and half the required secondary current.

**Transformer without centre tap**

[image]

The transformer without centre tap is to be wound for the required secondary voltage and the required secondary current.

> I have done all the work making the non center tap transformer and am using a full bridge rectifier for rectification. but when on low setting, instead of charging at 2 A it's charging at 10 A. The DC voltage on both machines is very nearly the same at about 15 V. I am puzzled why the charging currents are so different. Can any one help?

The transformers of vintage battery chargers were wound with 'high impedance' secondaries in order to obtain poor regulation and thereby limit charging current.

Filter capacitors were also not used.

Hence the open-circuit DC voltage would be the secondary voltage minus the rectifier voltage drop.

The problem with your transformer is that it is 'too good' (over-rated) for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use any kind of transformer, center tapped or not, if it is otherwise suitable for the task.

The center tapped transformer just uses a half bridge rectifier. You can use a transformer without a center tap and a full bridge rectifier.

Answer (score 1):

> The DC voltage on both machines is very nearly the same at about 15
> volts. I am puzzled why the charging amps are so different.

When AC is full-wave rectified it doesn't produce pure DC, but a series of half sine waves with a peak voltage equaling the [rms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) voltage multiplied by ~1.4 and average voltage multiplied by ~1.6.

On DC ranges your multimeter reads average voltage, but the battery charges whenever the instantaneous charger voltage exceeds the voltage on the battery. Charging current depends on the difference between the **peak** charger voltage and battery voltage, and the total [resistance](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/resis.html) of the circuit (including transformer windings, diodes, wiring, battery internal resistance etc.).

To give an idea of what the waveforms look like I created a simulation of a simple 12V battery charger in [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html). With resting battery voltage set to 14 V the numeric results were as follows:-

- rms transformer output voltage: 14.6 V
- average charger output and battery voltage:- 15 V
- rms charging current:- 10.5 A

However the waveforms tell a different story. Peak charging current is 20 A, and peak battery voltage is 17 V.

[image]

> I have a battery charger which has a center tap on the secondary
> winding and uses two diodes for rectification . **When set on low** it
> charges at about 2 amps DC.

This charger must have something in it to set the charge rate, perhaps different voltage taps on the transformer or a resistor to reduce current.

The center-tapped transformer only uses one half of the output winding per AC half cycle, so its resistance will be about double that of a similar transformer with single winding because it has to fit twice as many turns into the same space.

For your own design you are using a transformer with no center tap that probably has much lower winding resistance. To compensate for this you need to add enough resistance to get the current you want. Try a 12 V 15~25 W automotive bulb.

Note that this simple battery charger does not limit the charging voltage, so the battery will 'gas' when it exceeds ~14.4V, splitting the water in the electrolyte into hydrogen and oxygen. This is an explosion hazard, and the battery will have to be topped up with pure (de-ionised) water.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting so much time. Let me go back to basics and ask you this. Let's say we have 16 turns on a single wound secondary to get let's say 14 volts out. Is this equivalent to a center tapped winding of each winding having 16 turns? Or the center tapped windings will have 8 turns in each winding giving a total of 16 turns? I am not at all clear about this. Thank you again. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: To get 14V from a center tapped winding you would need 16 turns on each side (making 14V+14V or 28V total).

Comment: Thanks. You have been great help.

Answer (score 0):

The centre tap would be 50% of the voltage.  If you are getting 15V, you can reduce that down 13 to  14.  with two 0.7V power diodes in series. If all you have are 1N400x type you might get away with sharing a few in parallel . (but they must be the same temp to share)

Wouldn't it be easier to buy another trickle charge?

Answer (score 0):

Your have two transformers not equal. Look like the second has higher voltage. Try to reduce secondary winds to adjust the current. Rectifiers is not so important, except in full bridge rectifier you getting bigger drop voltage. It is because the current passing through two diodes. And bigger heatsink should be.